# Add columns to reflect the number of occurrences of a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sorted dataframe that looks like this:

| Name | Year | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2019 | 10 |
| a | 2020 | 20 |
| a | 2021 | 30 |
| b | 2015 | 55 |
| b | 2019 | 75 |
| c | 2011 | 15 |

I want to add more "Price" columns that correspond to the number of occurrences of "Name" so that the dataframe can look like this:

| Name | Year | Price | Price_2 | Price_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2019 | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| a | 2020 | 20 | 10 | 0 |
| a | 2021 | 30 | 10 | 20 |
| b | 2015 | 55 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 2019 | 75 | 55 | 0 |
| c | 2011 | 15 | 0 | 0 |

For example, the first instance of 'a' has a price of 10. The second instance of 'a' has a price of 20. I would like to add a column to reflect the price of that first instance of 'a', which was 10.

The greatest number of occurrences of a name in my dataset is 4, so adding too many columns should not be an issue.

I've tried creating a list for names that have 2 occurrences, a list for names that have 3 occurrences, etc. Then I tried appending these lists to the dataframe. Though the issue here is adding the 0's in the correct places such that the list appends appropriately.

I've been struggling with this for a little while now, as I'm still getting used to Python and Pandas.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why is Price_3 = 75 in row 2?

Comment: Can you check your output please or explain the logic with another example?

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. I copied the data incorrectly when creating the sample dataframe (first time using stackoverflow haha). Price_3 = 20 in row 3, and reflects the second instance of 'a' from year 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that relies heavily on lists/arrays and the [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

---

#### Input Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
    'Name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
    'Year': [2019, 2020, 2021, 2015, 2019, 2011],
    'Price': [10, 20, 30, 55, 75, 15]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Year'])

print(df)
```

```
  Name  Year  Price
0    a  2019     10
1    a  2020     20
2    a  2021     30
3    b  2015     55
4    b  2019     75
5    c  2011     15
```

---

#### Step 1: Cummulatively append the prices in lists

First start by using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the DataFrame rows by the `Name` field.

Then use the `.apply()` method twice on the `Price` field of each group, a nested one to convert each price to a list, and an outer one to perform a running "sum" on them using the [`.cumsum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) method.

To ensure the lists are in the correct order (according to your desired output), there is one more use of `.apply()`, to have the most recently appended value is put at the front.

```py
# Group by name
name_groups= df.groupby('Name')

# For each name group, cumulatively append the prices in lists
price_lists = name_groups['Price'].apply(lambda gp: gp.apply(
                                             lambda p: [p]).cumsum()
                                        ).apply(lambda x: [x[-1]] + x[0:-1])

print(price_lists)
```

Current output:

```
0            [10]
1        [20, 10]
2    [30, 10, 20]
3            [55]
4        [75, 55]
5            [15]
Name: Price, dtype: object
```

---

#### Step 2: Pad out the lists with zeros

To calculate the maximum number of price columns for your DataFrame, find the maximum number of duplicate names (in your case, the value is `3` since `'a'` has the most duplicates, three in total).

Then use [`np.pad()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) on each of the lists to have them all have lengths that match this value, filling them in with zeros on the right.

```py
# Get the highest number of name duplicates.
max_names = max(name_groups.size())

# Pad each of these lists with zeros (as a numpy array), having a length equal to max_names
price_arrays = price_lists.apply(lambda x: np.pad(x, [0, max_names - len(x)]))

print(price_arrays)
```

Current output:

```
0      [10, 0, 0]
1     [20, 10, 0]
2    [30, 10, 20]
3      [55, 0, 0]
4     [75, 55, 0]
5      [15, 0, 0]
Name: Price, dtype: object
```

---

#### Step 3: Adding the values to the DataFrame as separate columns

Specify the column labels that will represent each of these list elements separately.

Then create a new DataFrame out of the list values, ensuring they are passed as a list of lists/arrays using the `.tolist()` method. The will automatically be represented as separate columns.

From there you can add these to the original DataFrame under the specified column names.

```py
# Generate the column names to store the results under.
cols = ['Price'] + [f'Price_{i}' for i in range(2, max_names + 1)]

# Add the values to the DataFrame under these column names
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(price_arrays.tolist())

print(df)
```

Final output:

```
  Name  Year  Price  Price_2  Price_3
0    a  2019     10        0        0
1    a  2020     20       10        0
2    a  2021     30       10       20
3    b  2015     55        0        0
4    b  2019     75       55        0
5    c  2011     15        0        0
```

---

#### Full code:

```py
# --- Step 1 ---
name_groups = df.groupby('Name')
price_lists = name_groups['Price'].apply(lambda gp: gp.apply(
                                             lambda p: [p]).cumsum()
                                        ).apply(lambda x: [x[-1]] + x[0:-1])

# --- Step 2 ---
max_names = max(name_groups.size())
price_arrays = price_lists.apply(lambda x: np.pad(x, [0, max_names - len(x)]))

# --- Step 3 ---
cols = ['Price'] + [f'Price_{i}' for i in range(2, max_names + 1)]
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(price_arrays.tolist())
```